# Eclipse RCP restart app from splash screen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, workbench, p2

I'm implementing a 3.x/e4 hybrid RCP app:

---

**TL;DR**

Login in splash -> update client if necessary -> restart workbench right after.

---

**Full story**

1. Splash screen shows up, and it has a login component in it. This is implemented by extending `AbstractSplashHandler`
2. User writes username, password, server address and port. Once the `Sign In` button is pressed, a P2 update check will be performed by contacting the server at the provided address.
3. If server is reacheable, and an update is available, then user is asked if we wants to update. These updates are mandatory, so he/she cannot enter the system unless it's up-to-date.
4. If user pressed YES, then the P2 update will be performed. After it is finished, I want to automatically restart the workbench.

Few problems with the restart:

1. In the splash lifecycle, the `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` doesn't return `null`, but neither is it fully initialized. So if I call `IWorkbench#restart` some internal NPEs are thrown (I can put them here on request).
2. I thought about doing the version checking in the `Application` class, where I can return the `IApplication.EXIT_RESTART` code - BUT I do not have the splash there, yet. And I really want to do the login in the splash.
3. Is there any middle ground between `IWorkbench#restart` and `System.exit(0)`? I would love to reach the point in the `Application` class, right after `PlatformUI#createAndRunWorkbench`, with the code for restart.